# Find the limit of $(x^2-1)(2-\cos x)$ as $x$ approaches $0$

Tags: calculus

I am stuck at this: $(x-1)(x+1)(2-\cos x)$.

I don't know what to do next. Help and thank you.

Comment: Why not just plug in $x=0$? You get $0^2\cdot (2-\cos 0)$ which you can calculate.

Comment: Sorry, it is actually (x^2-1)

Comment: Doesn't make any difference. Substitute.

Comment: so, then you get $(0^2 - 1)\cdot (a-\cos(0))$. Where is the problem in calculating this?

Comment: I had a brain fart. Thank you for helping everyone. Much appreciated

Comment: you are welcome,dont be shame for asking even simple question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if we have

$(x^2-1)*(2-cos(x))$

we can  see that at $x=0$,

this is  defined and is equal $(0^2-1)*(2-cos(0))=-1*1=-1$

Comment: sorry i have wrote   cos(0) as 0 incorrectly,i have fixed